# keras model with tf.contrib.losses.metric_learning.triplet_semihard_loss Assertion error

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am using python 3 with anaconda, and trying to use a tf.contrib loss function with a Keras model.

The code is the following

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.contrib.losses import metric_learning
model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Dense(50,  activation="relu"))
model.compile(loss=metric_learning.triplet_semihard_loss, optimizer=Adam())
```

I get the following error:

> File
>   "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py",
>   line 404, in weighted
>       score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/siamese/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/losses/python/metric_learning/metric_loss_ops.py",
>   line 179, in triplet_semihard_loss
>       assert lshape.shape == 1 AssertionError

When I am using the same network  with a keras loss function it works fine, I tried to wrap the tf loss function in a function like so

```
def func(y_true, y_pred): 
    import tensorflow as tf
    return tf.contrib.losses.metric_learning.triplet_semihard_loss(y_true, y_pred)
```

And still getting the same error

What am I doing wrong here?

update: 
When changing the func to return the following

```
return K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
```

everything works fine!
But i cant get it to work with the specific tf loss function...

When i go into tf.contrib.losses.metric_learning.triplet_semihard_loss and remove this line of code: `assert lshape.shape == 1` it runs fine

Thanks

Comment: Still not clear *where exactly* your error pops up; is it during `fit`? During `compile`? Posting the full error trace would be a good idea...

Comment: @desertnaut the error is in the compile function. When i go into tf.contrib.losses.metric_learning.triplet_semihard_loss and remove this line of code: assert lshape.shape == 1 it runs fine

Comment: Hello, I have too same problem, but the solution turned so easy. You just replace the arguments. First set labels and then set embeddings.

Comment: @thebeancounter Hey! Were you able to solve it? I am facing the same problem and can't figure out how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you pass wrong input to the loss function.

According to [triplet_semihard_loss docstring](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.12.0/tensorflow/contrib/losses/python/metric_learning/metric_loss_ops.py) you need to pass `labels` and `embeddings`.

So your code have to be:

```
def func(y, embeddings): 
    return tf.contrib.losses.metric_learning.triplet_semihard_loss(labels=y, embeddings=embeddings)
```

And two more notes about network for embeddings:

1. Last dense layer has to be without activation
2. Don't forget to normalise output vector `model.add(Lambda(lambda x: K.l2_normalize(x, axis=1)))`

Comment: why would you say the input is wrong? labels=y_true seems to me similar to what you are writing here

Answer (score -1):

It seems that your problem comes from an incorrect input in the loss function. In fact, the triplet loss wants the parameters:

```
Args:
labels: 1-D tf.int32 `Tensor` with shape [batch_size] of
  multiclass integer labels.
embeddings: 2-D float `Tensor` of embedding vectors. Embeddings should
  be l2 normalized.
```

Are you sure that `y_true` has the correct shape? Can you give us more details about the tensors you are using?

Comment: This is crashing before even getting the y-true or any input for that matter. It crashes in the compile stage

Comment: It crashes before running any computation because Tensorflow builds the computation graph in the first place, so if there is some mismatch among tensors' dimensions it will raise an error even before feeding any placeholder with its value. It is absolutely normal, then any other information may help to debug your code

Comment: the issue is that in the loss function there is an assert, checking that the y_true shape is 2d or more, but this loss function is using y_true as a single dimension vector of integers (labels) so it does not make any sense, i removed the assert and it's working fine @gabriele